# mysql spatial data speed

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have a table with (among others) `x` and `y` fields of SMALLINT type and `pt` of POINT type, set to POINT(`x`,`y`);
`x` and `y` have normal indecies and `pt` has a spatial index set.

Profiling typical query

```
select sql_no_cache
    count(0) from `table_name`
    where (x between -50 and 50)
    and (y between -50 and 50);
-- vs
set @g = GeomFromText('Polygon((-50 -50, 50 -50, 50 50, -50 50, -50 -50))');
select sql_no_cache
    count(0) from `table_name`
    where MBRContains(@g, `pt`);
```

... shows that query via `x` and `y` is 1.5 times faster:
3.45±0.10ms vs 4.61±0.14ms over 10 queries.
`x` and `y` would always be INT and only rectangular (even square) areas would be queried. Yes, this is carved in stone ;-)

The main question is:
**Have I missed something about indecies or is spatial data an overkill in such case?**

- MySQL version is 5.1.37
- DB Engine type is MyISAM (default)
- Current table size is 5k rows, 10-30k planned in production.

I have had some experience with MySQL, but never worked with spatial data types and spatial indecies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a combined x & y INDEX on the table? If so then yes, this is extremely fast.
I believe Spatial indexes have more broad use. A polygon structure can have many vertices and the rectangle is a single case of a more generic construct.

If a rectangular boundary area is enough for your needs then I would rather suggest you go with the x and y fields solution than adding the complexity of the geospatial extension features.

Comment: Hmm, didn't saw any combined indecies in that version of MySQL

Comment: By *combined index* I mean an INDEX on two or more fields. I believe any version of MySQL does that.


You can add an INDEX on both x & y columns:
    ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX(`x`,`y`);

Keep in mind that queries using condition only on the `x` field will benefit from this index, 

    SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE x BETWEEN 100 AND 200;

while queries with a condition only using the `y` field will NOT use this index.